# How to add class to all elements in collection excluding one

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a simple slider. I have 3 slides and arrows to move left and right. Also I have a counter variable set to 0. By clicking on right button I want to make this: I want to iterate through the collection of my slide elements to assign class 'hide' to all of them but one element which is equal to count + 1 (next slide).

````
let slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
let rightCaret = document.querySelector('.rightCaret');


// numerating all the li elements (slides) giving them ids
setIdToEachSlide = function() {
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].id = i;
    }
};

setIdToEachSlide();

rightCaret.addEventListener('click', function () {
    slides.forEach(element => {
        if (element.id == count + 1) {
            continue;
        } else {
            element.classList.add('hide');
        }
    });
});```

I expected my function to set every slide but the next one class 'hide' but it sets this class to every slide
````

Comment: Consider inverting your `slides.forEach` logic, and remove the `continue` expression.

Comment: Sorry. English is not my native language. What do you mean by inverting the logic?

Comment: You’re logic says “if equal then continue else hide” I’d suggest changing it to “if not equal then hide” removing the need for an else statement.

Answer (score 0):

The `continue` instruction does not work with/inside `forEach`.

Instead you could just remove the `hide`-class from the current slide and add it to all other slides. You also should declare the `count`-variable before using it.

**Example:**

```js
let slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
let rightCaret = document.querySelector('.rightCaret');

function setIdToEachSlide() {
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].id = i;
  }
}
setIdToEachSlide();

let count = 0;
rightCaret.addEventListener('click', function() {
  count++;
  if (count > slides.length - 1) {
    return; // we are on the last slide, nothing todo!
  }
  slides.forEach(element => {
    if (element.id == count) {
      element.classList.remove('hide');
    } else {
      element.classList.add('hide');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="slide">Slide 1</li>
  <li class="slide hide">Slide 2</li>
  <li class="slide hide">Slide 3</li>
  <li class="slide hide">Slide 4</li>
  <li class="slide hide">Slide 5</li>
</ul>
<button class="rightCaret">&gt;</button>
```